# Trouble with local restaurant automated breakfast billing (c++)

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and I'm having trouble with an assignment. I need help with the errors when I compile as well has how to do the calculations for tax and total amount due. Here is the assignment...

Write a program to help a local restaurant automate its breakfast billing system. The program should do the following:
a.  Show the customer the different breakfast items offered by the restaurant.
b.  Allow the customer to select more than one item from the menu
c.  Calculate and print the bill
Assume that the restaurant offers the following breakfast items (the price of each item is shown to the right of the item):

Plain Egg                   $1.45
Bacon and Egg                   $2.45
Muffin                      $0.99
French Toast                    $1.99
Fruit Basket                    $2.44
Cereal                      $0.69
Coffee                      $0.50
Tea                     $0.75

First, Define a struct, menuItemType, with two components: menuItem of type string and menuPrice of type double.
Then use an array, call it menuList, of the struct menuItemType. Your program must contain the following functions:
•   Function getData: This function loads the data into the array menulist.
•   Function showMenu: This function shows the different items offered by the restaurant and tells the user how to select the items.
•   Function printCheck: This function calculates and prints the check. (Note that the billing amount should include a 5% tax)

Sample output:

Welcome to Johnny’s Restaurant
Bacon and Egg                   $2.45
Muffin                      $0.99
Coffee                      $0.50
   Tax                      $0.20
   Amount Due                   $4.14

**HERE is my code so far**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct menuItemType
{
    string menuItem;
    double menuPrice;
};

void getData(menuItemType menuList[8]);
void showMenu(menuItemType menuList[8], menuItemType orderList[], int orderCounter, int selection);
void printCheck(menuItemType menuList[8], int orderCounter, const double TAX);

const int MAX = 8;
const double TAX = 1.05;

int main()
{
    int orderCounter = 0;
    int selection = ' ';

    menuItemType menuList[8];
    menuItemType orderList[MAX];

    getData(menuList);
    showMenu(menuList, orderList, orderCounter, selection);
    printCheck(orderList, orderCounter, TAX);

return 0;
}

void getData(menuItemType menuList[8])
{

menuList[0].menuItem = "Plain Egg";
menuList[0].menuPrice = 1.45;
menuList[1].menuItem = "Bacon and Egg";
menuList[1].menuPrice = 2.45;
menuList[2].menuItem = "Muffin";
menuList[2].menuPrice = 0.99;
menuList[3].menuItem = "French Toast";
menuList[3].menuPrice = 1.99;
menuList[4].menuItem = "Fruit Basket";
menuList[4].menuPrice = 2.49;
menuList[5].menuItem = "Cereal";
menuList[5].menuPrice = 0.69;
menuList[6].menuItem = "Coffee";
menuList[6].menuPrice = 0.50;
menuList[7].menuItem = "Tea";
menuList[7].menuPrice = 0.75;

}

void showMenu(menuItemType menuList[8], menuItemType orderList[], int orderCounter, int selection)
{
cout << "1 - Plain Egg" << setw(14) << "$1.45" << endl;
cout << "2 - Bacon and Egg" << setw(10) << "$2.45" << endl;
cout << "3 - Muffin" << setw(17) << "$0.99" << endl;
cout << "4 - French Toast" << setw(11) << "$1.99" << endl;
cout << "5 - Fruit Basket" << setw(11) << "$2.49" << endl;
cout << "6 - Cereal" << setw(17) << "$0.69" << endl;
cout << "7 - Coffee" << setw(17) << "$0.50" << endl;
cout << "8 - Tea" << setw(21) << "$0.75\n" << endl;
}

do{
    cout << "Enter the number of your selection until you have completed your order." << endl;
    cout << "Enter 9 when you have finished." << endl;
    cin >> selection;

    Switch(selection)
        {
            case 9:
            break;
            case 1:
            cout << menuList[0].menuItem << setw(14) << "$1.45";
            break;
            case 2:
            cout << menuList[1].menuItem << setw(10) << "$2.45";
            break;
            case 3:
            cout << menuList[2].menuItem << setw(17) << "$0.99";
            break;
            case 4:
            cout << menuList[3].menuItem << setw(11) << "$1.99";
            break;
            case 5:
            cout << menuList[4].menuItem << setw(11) << "$2.49";
            break;
            case 6:
            cout << menuList[5].menuItem << setw(17) << "$0.69";
            break;
            case 7:
            cout << menuList[6].menuItem << setw(17) << "$0.50";
            break;
            case 8:
            cout << menuList[7].menuItem << setw(20) << "$0.75";
            break;
            default:
            cout << "Invalid Selection! Selections must be between 1 and 9\n";
    }
}
{
while (selection !=9);
    if((selection >=0) && (selection <= MAX))
    {
        orderList[orderCounter].menuItem = menuList[selection-1].menuItem;
        orderList[orderCounter].menuPrice = menuList[selection-1.menuPrice;
        orderCounter++;
    }
    else if (selection == 9)
        cout << "Exit" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Invalid Entry" << endl;
    }
}
void printCheck(menuItemType orderList[], int orderCounter, const double TAX)
{
    cout << "Welcome to the Breakfast Place!"<< endl;

    for (int corderCounter = 0; orderCounter < MAX; orderCounter++)
        cout << orderList[orderCounter].menuItem << " "
        << orderList[orderCounter].menuPrice<< endl;
        cout << "Tax" << setw(10) << endl;
        cout << "Amount Due" << setw(10) << endl;

}
```

**And here are my errors when I try to debug**

```
>  BreakfastBilling.cpp
1>breakfastbilling.cpp(69): error C2059: syntax error : 'do'

1>breakfastbilling.cpp(69): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

1>breakfastbilling.cpp(69): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

1>breakfastbilling.cpp(106): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

1>breakfastbilling.cpp(111): error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'

1>breakfastbilling.cpp(119): error C2059: syntax error : '}'

1>breakfastbilling.cpp(119): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'

1>breakfastbilling.cpp(119): error C2059: syntax error : '}'

1>breakfastbilling.cpp(121): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

1>breakfastbilling.cpp(121): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: It looks like you have a syntax error, more specifically, you have a `do` statement outside of a method.  Proper indentation should give you visibility on where the problem may lie.

Comment: where would be the best place to put the do statement?

Comment: Lots and lots of hardcoding here. If the price of eggs were to go up then you would have to recompile your program.

Comment: -1 I'm voting to close as 'too broad', because there are too many design flaws and errors to fix in the code.

Comment: The problem is that after the cout for tea, you have a closing curly brace which corresponds with the opening curly brace of the function body for ShowMenu().  This  is one of several brace placement errors that you have in this source code.

Answer (score 1):

Now this finally works.....

It had errors such as -

1. Tried copy string by assignment operator. You should use `strcpy()` for that.

2. Declared variables locally and used them globally.

3. Had typing mistakes.

4. The code does not contain declaration for the Net Amount which is to be printed at last.

5. TAX was never used, which then I used at last where the final results where displayed.

6. while and switch was declared outside a function/method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace::std;    

struct menuItemType
{
    char menuItem[20];
    double menuPrice;
};

void getData(menuItemType menuList[8]);
void showMenu(menuItemType menuList[8], menuItemType orderList[], int orderCounter, int selection);
void printCheck(menuItemType menuList[8], int orderCounter, const double TAX);

const int MAX = 8;
const double TAX = 1.05;

menuItemType menuList[8];
menuItemType orderList[MAX];

int main()
{
    int orderCounter = 0;
    int selection = ' ';



    getData(menuList);
    showMenu(menuList, orderList, orderCounter, selection);
    printCheck(orderList, orderCounter, TAX);

return 0;
}

void getData(menuItemType menuList[8])
{

strcpy(menuList[0].menuItem,"Plain Egg");
menuList[0].menuPrice = 1.45;
strcpy(menuList[1].menuItem,"Bacon and Egg");
menuList[1].menuPrice = 2.45;
strcpy(menuList[2].menuItem,"Muffin");
menuList[2].menuPrice = 0.99;
strcpy(menuList[3].menuItem,"French Toast");
menuList[3].menuPrice = 1.99;
strcpy(menuList[4].menuItem,"Fruit Basket");
menuList[4].menuPrice = 2.49;
strcpy(menuList[5].menuItem,"Cereal");
menuList[5].menuPrice = 0.69;
strcpy(menuList[6].menuItem,"Coffee");
menuList[6].menuPrice = 0.50;
strcpy(menuList[7].menuItem,"Tea");
menuList[7].menuPrice = 0.75;

}

void showMenu(menuItemType menuList[8], menuItemType orderList[], int orderCounter, int selection)
{
cout << "1 - Plain Egg" << setw(14) << "$1.45" << endl;
cout << "2 - Bacon and Egg" << setw(10) << "$2.45" << endl;
cout << "3 - Muffin" << setw(17) << "$0.99" << endl;
cout << "4 - French Toast" << setw(11) << "$1.99" << endl;
cout << "5 - Fruit Basket" << setw(11) << "$2.49" << endl;
cout << "6 - Cereal" << setw(17) << "$0.69" << endl;
cout << "7 - Coffee" << setw(17) << "$0.50" << endl;
cout << "8 - Tea" << setw(21) << "$0.75\n" << endl;
do{
    cout << "Enter the number of your selection until you have completed your order." << endl;
    cout << "Enter 9 when you have finished." << endl;
    cin >> selection;

    switch(selection)
    {
        case 9:
        break;
        case 1:
        cout << menuList[0].menuItem << setw(14) << "$1.45";
        break;
        case 2:
        cout << menuList[1].menuItem << setw(10) << "$2.45";
        break;
        case 3:
        cout << menuList[2].menuItem << setw(17) << "$0.99";
        break;
        case 4:
        cout << menuList[3].menuItem << setw(11) << "$1.99";
        break;
        case 5:
        cout << menuList[4].menuItem << setw(11) << "$2.49";
        break;
        case 6:
        cout << menuList[5].menuItem << setw(17) << "$0.69";
        break;
        case 7:
        cout << menuList[6].menuItem << setw(17) << "$0.50";
        break;
        case 8:
        cout << menuList[7].menuItem << setw(20) << "$0.75";
        break;
        default:
        cout << "Invalid Selection! Selections must be between 1 and 9\n";
    }
}while (selection !=9);
    if((selection >=0) && (selection <= MAX))
    {
    strcpy(orderList[orderCounter].menuItem, menuList[selection-1].menuItem);
    orderList[orderCounter].menuPrice = menuList[selection-1].menuPrice;
    orderCounter++;
    }
    else if (selection == 9)
    cout << "Exit" << endl;
    else
    cout << "Invalid Entry" << endl;

}


void printCheck(menuItemType orderList[], int orderCounter, const double TAX)
{
    cout << "Welcome to the Breakfast Place!"<< endl;

    for (orderCounter = 0; orderCounter < MAX; orderCounter++)
    cout << orderList[orderCounter].menuItem << " "<< orderList[orderCounter].menuPrice<< endl;
    cout << "Tax" << setw(10) << TAX<<endl;
    cout << "Amount Due" << setw(10) << endl;

}
```

The above code is rectified, but the logical errors are still there, you should look at them as you have not mentioned your logics in your code. The `amount` is still not displayed as you haven't added a code for that!

Answer (score 1):

You initialized orderCounter in main but you are not returning it in any function so in the end it still will be 0. Same thing goes for arrays. Functions in c++ are working on copies of passed data unless arguments are passed by reference or pointers. In your case you may want to use global declarations for orderCounter and arrays of your structs.  It is NOT the best solution but it works. Or if you want to stick to your current code read a little about functions and passing arguments. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/